# Is there any flaw in this code?

Tags: java, servlets, concurrency

I wrote a servlet, but the servlet is not yet in production stage.

I've added a counter in the Filter of the servlet, so that when number of concurrent request reach a limit, no more people can be accepted. I worry some marginal case, for example: Say the system has already reached 49 concurrent request(50 is max), and in the synchronized block it makes the boolean variable "ok" to True, then at the next instance, multiple thread see that the servlet is available and rush into that and break the limit.

Please help to check this code if there is any flaw:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // place your code here

        // pass the request along the filter chain
        conditionalInfoLog(logEnabled, "Incoming request...");
        conditionalInfoLog(logEnabled, "Number of concurrent request(s): " + count);
        boolean ok;
        synchronized (lock) {
            ok = count < limit;
            if(ok){
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (ok) {
            try{
                // let the request through and process as usual
                conditionalInfoLog(logEnabled, "Request accepted and processing, number of concurrent request(s): " + count);
                chain.doFilter(request, response);

            }catch(Exception ex){
                conditionalErrorLog(logEnabled, ex.getMessage());
                String xmlStr = genXmlErrMsg(ex.getMessage());
                response.setContentType("text/xml");
                response.getWriter().print(xmlStr);
            }finally{
                synchronized (lock) {
                    count--;
                }
                conditionalInfoLog(logEnabled, "End of request. Number of concurrent request(s): " + count);
            }
        } else {
            // handle limit case, e.g. return status code 503
            conditionalInfoLog(logEnabled, busyMsg);
            String xmlStr = genXmlErrMsg(busyMsg);
            response.setContentType("text/xml");
            response.getWriter().print(xmlStr);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What did your unit testing tell you? How about your integration testing, stress testing, or user acceptance testing? Or are you going to push this into production based on a few comments from some random Joes on the net. Your company must be an absolutely thrilling place to work at :-)

Comment: What if **one** person sends 50 requests at once? Must others suffer from this?

Comment: This program is far from UAT, it is a 2nd contingency program

Comment: @BalusC, we don't care attack in this stage, other people have to wait if there is too many requests.

Comment: Ah so. Well, I'd rather configure it at container level.

Comment: In this way, we can monitor the situation by looking through the log. Don't know if we can know the current concurrent request in the container.

Comment: What about posting it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Monitoring can be done by JMX. Tomcat, for example again, also just supports it: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/monitoring.html. There are Java based APIs/tools which visualizes it nicely, such as JavaMelody http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/ It look more and more that you've to comminucate this kind of requirements/issues better with your manager and/or serveradmin. This clearly isn't the developer's responsibility.

Answer (score 5):

I'd rather configure it at servletcontainer level than trying to fiddle something together. A bit decent servletcontainer is thoroughly tested and surely production ready.

Tomcat, for example, has a `maxThreads` attribute exactly for this purpose. You can set it in the `<Connector>` element in `server.xml`.

```
<Connector maxThreads="50" ...>
```

This puts a limit on amount of simultaneous requests (which defaults to 200 by the way). So when there's an 51st request, it's just put in a queue (whose length is configureable by `acceptCounts` attribute by the way) until the first is ready. This is also a bit more user friendly than a 503.

#### See also:

- [Tomcat 7.0 documentation - The HTTP Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)

Comment: +1: Why write your own `Filter` when the container can do it for you.

Comment: We use websphere in production. Don't know how to do it.

Comment: The serveradmin is the one responsible for it. By the way, Websphere uses a fork of Tomcat as servletcontainer. So lot of configuration settings should look familiar.

Comment: Please tell me how to do that in websphere. Searched in google but failed

Comment: Seeing the absence of any progress on this issue and your subsequent questions which made the hairs in my neck raise, I have the slight impression that you're actually the serveradmin yourself or that you fear the real serveradmin. What is it? Must I take your hand in digging the manual so that you can finally do the *right* thing?

Answer (score 3):

It is correct, but you are basically reinventing a `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`:

```
class MyFilter {
  final Semaphore permits = new Semaphore(50);

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (permits.tryAcquire()) {
        try {
          … // execute
        } finally {
          permits.release();
        }
    } else {
      … // handle limit case, e.g. return status code 503
    }
  }
}
```

This class is much more efficient than your hand-rolled solution and better expresses your intent anyway.

Comment: does the permits variable need to be static so need it is shared among thread? I am afraid in your code it is a instance for each thread?

Comment: I heard that semaphore will produce deadlock, are you sure about using semaphore?

Comment: the Servlet instance is shared between the threads. static means that the variable is held on the Class object (of which there is only one per classloader that loaded the class). The servlet container is responsible for loading a servlet and sharing the instance between the request threads.

Comment: As far as producing deadlocks go, Semaphore is in exactly the same boat as an array of locks (you can conceptually thing of it as such). Locks don't compose very well, so if you are taking one and then calling other code that may take another one, you have to be very careful about any code that does the reverse. Secondly, you _must_ release the permit (or unlock the lock) in a `finally` block otherwise an exception will cause the permit to be "lost", this can lead to eventual starvation which looks a bit like a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

At most one thread at a time is allowed synchronize on an object. If several threads try to "rush into" a synchronized block, only one will make it. Also, each thread will have its local copy of `ok`, and each thread will have to make it through this block:

```
synchronized (lock) {
    ok = count < limit;
    if (ok) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

before it can test the value of it's `ok` variable. So I think this is pretty safe.

It's good that you also synchronize the decrement of `count` later on; this will ensure that the value of `count` will be flushed to memory before any other thread can enter a block that synchronizes on `lock`.